# Adding two Model Class

Tags: yii

In Category Model, getAll method is used for returning all category data. First Active Record in below method $roots have all roots category and $categories have roots category's descendants category. How to add these two Category. Following is getAll Method:

```
   public function getAll()
    {
      $roots = Category::model()->roots()->findAll();
      foreach($roots as $root)
      {
        $category = Category::model()->findByPk($root->root);   
        $categories = $category->descendants()->findAll();
      }
      return $category + $categories;  // this does not concatenate, causes error   
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems here:

1. You are only going to get the `category` and `descendants` of the last root in your table because the `foreach` loop will overwrite the variables each time.  To prevent this, you will need to make `$categoriy` and `$categories` arrays, and assign like `$category[] = ...` and `$categories[] = ...`. Or maybe better you could merge them into a composite array at the end of the loop.  Maybe something like this:

   ```
   foreach($roots as $root)
     {
       $category = Category::model()->findByPk($root->root);   
       $categories[] = $category;
       $categories = array_merge($categories, $category->descendants()->findAll());
     }
   return $categories;
   ```

   You now have an array of all root and descendent categories stored as root category, then its descendents, then the next root category, then its descendents, etc.
2. `$category` is a `Category` object as written, and `$categories` is an array of `descendants()`.  I am hoping that these are `Category` objects as well.  But you can't concatenate an object with an array, you have to use array_merge(), see my example above.